# rDGAL, Tiff Files, and WorldFile

Tags: latitude-longitude, pixel, r-sp, rgdal, map-projections

I have a set of tiff files that display convective weather across the continental US (NAD83 projection) in pixel locations from [Iowa State University](http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/archive/data/2016/01/01/GIS/uscomp/n0r_201601011100.png). My goal is the transformation of the pixel locations to lat/lon data. I read in the tiff file data as a SpatialGridDataFrame with...

```
imageData   = readGDAL( fileNameDir, silent = TRUE )
```

I read somewhere that readGDAL will seek a World File if no projection data exist in the tiff file, so I created such a file (nad83WorldFile.wld) with the requisite information, [see info at ESRI](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/world-files-for-raster-datasets.htm).  I put the wld file in the same directory as my R scripts.  The coefficients for the wld file are:

```
A = 0.01 
B = 0.0 
C = 0.0 
D = -0.01 
E = -126.0 
F = 50.0
```

I seek advice and guidance on the pixel-to-lat/lon projection.  A data file for the readGDAL example of fileNameDir and documentation on the World File format are provided in the hypertext links above.  I had to change the file extension from *.png to *.tiff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, if you know that your data are projected, but that this projection isn't part of your tif file, your can simply add it in your R object after the import:

```
proj4string(imageData) <- CRS("your projection")
```

I like using EPSG for that, if your tif was in GoogleEarth projection for example I would do:

```
proj4string(imageData) <- CRS("+init=EPSG:4326")
```

Just find what you NAD83 exact projection is (this site can help http://spatialreference.org/).

Then you can reproject it in the your choice of projection:

```
imageDataProj <- spTransform(imageDataProj, CRS("your new projection"))
```

As a side note, I always prefer using the `raster` package for handling raster formats.  However, changing the projection of a big raster file with R can be fastidious, so now I use GDAL directly (through `gdalwarp`).  You can call all gdal options quite easily in R with the `gdalUtils` package but you'll have to import the results back into R after hand.

EDITS following comment from OP:

Using the raster package:

```
library(raster)
```

Loading the tif:

```
rr <- raster("C:\\temp\\n0r_201601011100.tif")
```

Save you pixel coordinates equations in functions.  Noticed I changed the Lat function (removed the negative sign, it didn't work with it, you'll have to validate that)

```
Lon = function(JJ) 0.01 * JJ + 162
Lat = function(II) 0.01 * II + 50.0
```

Get the extent of your raw raster in pixel coordinates:

```
ext.rr <- extent(rr)
```

Prepare a new empty raster which will be projected, have the good resolution and extent:

```
rr2 <- raster(nrows=nrow(rr), ncols=ncol(rr), xmn=Lon(ext.rr@xmin), xmx=Lon(ext.rr@xmax), ymn=Lat(ext.rr@ymin), ymx=Lat(ext.rr@ymax))
```

Fill this new raster with your modified values (following the equation you gave in the comments):

```
values(rr2) <- (values(rr) - 7) * 5
```

And you get:

```
rr2
   class       : RasterLayer 
   dimensions  : 2600, 6000, 15600000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
   resolution  : 0.01, 0.01  (x, y)
   extent      : 162, 222, 50, 76  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
   coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
   data source : in memory
   names       : layer 
   values      : -35, 50  (min, max)
```

Notice that the lat-long projection was automatically pick-up by the raster function.  Hopefully it's what you are looking for.

Comment: This is helpful.  My data are in pixel coordinates: `Lat = -0.01*I + 50.0`, `Lon = 0.01 * J + 162.`, where I and J are the rectilinear coordinates of each cell in the grid.  So, I need to do this first before performing any projection changes.  Also, what's the best way to transform the integer values in each cell with: `y = ( intX - 7 ) * 5`?

Comment: I bow in humble respect.  Thank you.

Comment: If you like the answer, can you accept it and upvote it please?

Comment: Of course, but I'm not sure if I know how to 'upvote' or if I have the privilege.

Comment: You can up vote with 15 rep (http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) to do so, just click on the gray triangle on top of the "0" in the higher left corner of my answer.  To accept the answer, you can simply click on the check mark below it.  If you never did that, you may want to go back to old questions you have posted where you got acceptable answers.  It's kind of the bread and butter of SO...

Comment: Fair enough; I will do so.