# Error in using over( spatialPoints, spatialPolygons )

Tags: r, r-sp, point-in-polygon

My goal is using the over() function in sp to determine which in which polygon a point exists.  I have this error ( Error: unexpected '>' in ">" ) on using:

```
over(ptsUTM, hex_grid)
```

where class( ptsUTM ) = "SpatialPoints" and class( hex_grid ) = "SpatialPolygons".  Both have the same @proj4string =

```
CRS arguments: +proj=utm +zone=14 +datum=WGS84 +units=km +no_defs +ellps=WGS84
```

The ptsUTM variable was created following the material in [rDGAL, Tiff Files, and WorldFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42100791/rdgal-tiff-files-and-worldfile), with these additions:

```
rr2[rr2<minDbzValue]  <- NA
pol <- rasterToPolygons(rr2, fun=function(x){ x >= minDbzValue } )
pol2                = spTransform( pol, "+proj=utm +zone=14 +datum=WGS84 +units=km" )
ptsUTM              = SpatialPoints( pol2 )
ptsUTM              = hex_grid@proj4string
```

and hex_grid was created following the material at [Fishnets and Honeycomb: Square vs. Hexagonal Spatial Grids](http://strimas.com/spatial/hexagonal-grids/)

Comment: Hi, can you clarify what the last two instructions are supposed to do  ? ( `ptsUTM = SpatialPoints( pol2 )` and `ptsUTM = hex_grid@proj4string`) Seems that first you are trying to transform polygons to points, and then you overwrite the result with a proj4string. In particular the last instruction seems to replace ptsUTM with a character string: therefore `over` can not work (unless I'm missing something)

Comment: Sure.  It's hard without providing all the code: rr2 is a raster object ;rasterToPolygons turns rr2 into a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame object, pol.  Then, spTransform adds the the CRS projection information to make pol2 (interim).  I used SpatialPoints to transform pol2 to a SpatialPoints object (ptsUTM) and add the projection information with the same CRS projection as hex_grid (is an object of SpatialPolygons).

Comment: Ok,  but my issue is that if you execute  `ptsUTM = hex_grid@proj4string` as it's written,  it seems to me that you are overwriting the variable,  not assigning the crs to it. Did you check the class of `ptsUTM` before the call to `over`

Comment: Mi scuzi, Lorenzo.  My mistake.  I became overwhelmed by information.  Thanks.

Comment: No worries.  Glad it helped.